# How to store tabular data in Python, to be able to search using different indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table of data, which I read from a database; something like:

| id | name | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 324234234 |
| 2 | Bob | 756756746 |
| ... |  |  |
| 999 | Zoe | 125785753 |

I know I can use a `dictionary`:

```
people = {}
cursor = self.db.query("SELECT * FROM people")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
  people[id] = row
```

Then, to search the `people` dictionary by `id`, I do:

```
id = 123
if (id in people):
  print(f"name of person with id {id} is {people[id].name}")
else:
  print(f"person with id {id} not found in people")
```

But I would like to be able to search (efficiently, in O(1) time) by `timestamp`, too:

So I ask if I can use a dictionary (and if yes, how to add secondary indexes?), or should I use some other data type?
I'd prefer using python internal data types, avoiding if possible external libraries.

Comment: Are timestamps unique? If yes, you can create other dictionary and query it by the timestamp.

Comment: Since the values in your dictionary are themselves single objects, you can easily create a second dictionary that uses another field (like timestamp) as the key, referencing the same objects as values, as long as the key is unique. However, you may also want to consider looking at commonly used libraries like numpy and pandas for dealing with this type of data and indexing it.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely: no, timestamps are not unique...

Comment: @MarcoS Then you can use dictonary consisting of lists and deal with duplicates...

Comment: why not use a pandas dataframe? Pandas was built for these types of questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Hojo.Timberwolf in comments, I feel obligated to point out that the pandas library does many of these things. However, you specify not introducing any additional dependencies, so here is my stab at it.

What you can do, is track each column of interest, and store them in additional dictionaries with some sort of reference to the rows they pertain too. This is what I believe @AndrejKesely was suggesting as well. In this case, I guessed that you would benefit from the advantages of having it ordered as well, so I included those features.

Here is an example code showing how this can be accomplished as a starting point. This is not a finished product, but should have all the key components to get you on your way.

```
import uuid


class MarcoSMultiIndex:
    def __init__(self, init_values: list[dict] = None, columns: list[str] = None):
        if init_values is None and columns is None:
            raise AssertionError('Class must be initialized with at least one of "columns" or "init_values" arguments')

        if columns:
            self._columns = list(columns)
        else:
            self._columns = list(init_values[0].keys())

        self._lookup = {
            column: dict() for column in self._columns
        }
        self._maindata = {}
        self._ordering = []

        if init_values:
            for item in init_values:
                self.append(item)

    def _TEST_PRINT(self):
        import json
        print('columns:')
        print(json.dumps(self._columns, indent=2))
        print('-' * 64)
        print('ordering:')
        print(json.dumps(self._ordering, indent=2))
        print('-' * 64)
        print('maindata:')
        print(json.dumps(self._maindata, indent=2))
        print('-' * 64)
        print('lookup:')
        print(json.dumps(self._lookup, indent=2))

    def _get_uuid(self):
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

    def keys(self):
        return list(self._columns)

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return self.keys()

    def append(self, new_row: dict):
        self.insert(len(self._ordering), new_row)

    def extend(self, new_rows: list):
        for new_row in new_rows:
            self.append(new_row)

    def insert(self, index: int, new_row: dict):
        new_uuid = self._get_uuid()
        for col in self._columns:
            if new_row.get(col, None) not in self._lookup[col]:
                self._lookup[col][new_row.get(col, None)] = list()
            self._lookup[col][new_row.get(col, None)].append(new_uuid)

        self._ordering.insert(index, new_uuid)
        self._maindata[new_uuid] = new_row

    def pop(self, index=None):
        out_uuid = self._ordering.pop(index or -1)
        out_row = self._maindata[out_uuid]
        self._remove(out_uuid, False)
        return out_row

    def clear(self):
        self.__init__(columns=self._columns)

    def count(self, column: str, value: str):
        return len(self._lookup[column][value])

    def sorted(self, column: str):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def reverse(self):
        self._ordering.reverse()

    def copy(self):
        return MarcoSMultiIndex(list(self), self._columns)

    def find(self, column, value):
        return [self._maindata[index] for index in self._lookup[column][value]]

    def _remove(self, out_uuid: str, remove_from_ordering=True):
        if remove_from_ordering:
            self._ordering.remove(out_uuid)
        removed_row = self._maindata[out_uuid]
        for col in self._columns:
            self._lookup[col][removed_row.get(col, None)].remove(out_uuid)
            if not len(self._lookup[col][removed_row.get(col, None)]):
                self._lookup[col].pop(removed_row.get(col, None))
        self._maindata.pop(out_uuid)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._maindata[self._ordering[index]]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._ordering)

    def __repr__(self):
        outstr = ''
        outstr += str(type(self))
        outstr += '\n'
        outstr += ''.join([f'{col:>15}' for col in self._columns])
        outstr += '\n'
        for index in self._ordering:
            outstr += ''.join([
                f'{self._maindata[index].get(col, ""):>15}'
                for col in self._columns
            ])
            outstr += '\n'
        return outstr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import string
    mmi = MarcoSMultiIndex(columns=['id', 'name', 'timestamp'])
    mmi.insert(10, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice', 'timestamp': 324234234})
    mmi.insert(10, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob', 'timestamp': 756756746})
    mmi.insert(10, {'id': 999, 'name': 'Zoe', 'timestamp': 125785753})
    mmi.insert(10, {'id': 999, 'name': 'sara', 'timestamp': 756756746, 'extra_column': 5})
    mmi.insert(10, {'id': 999, 'name': 'sara'}) # Missing timestamp column
    # mmi._TEST_PRINT()
    print(mmi)
    print(mmi.find('id', 2))
    print(mmi.find('id', 999))
```

And here is what I get when I run that:

```
<class '__main__.MarcoSMultiIndex'>
             id           name      timestamp
              1          Alice      324234234
              2            Bob      756756746
            999            Zoe      125785753
            999           sara      756756746
            999           sara               

[{'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob', 'timestamp': 756756746}]
[{'id': 999, 'name': 'Zoe', 'timestamp': 125785753}, {'id': 999, 'name': 'sara', 'timestamp': 756756746, 'extra_column': 5}, {'id': 999, 'name': 'sara'}]
```

Let me know if you have any questions.